# How do I get the number of times a grade appears

Tags: php

I'm trying to display the number of times each grade appears in a student's report sheet.

[grades](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMFVj.jpg)

In this image, the student has 5Bs and 2Cs.
How do I display it?

**This is how I got the grades**

```php
<?php $i = 1;
$total = 0;
$count = count($subjectScores);
foreach ($subjectScores as $value) { ?>
    <?php

    if ($value->tot_score >= 90 && $value->tot_score <= 100) {
        $grade = 'A+';
        $remark = 'DISTINCTION';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 80 && $value->tot_score <= 89.99) {
        $grade = 'A';
        $remark = 'EXCELLENT';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 70 && $value->tot_score <= 79.99) {
        $grade = 'B+';
        $remark = 'VERY GOOD';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 60 && $value->tot_score <= 69.99) {
        $grade = 'B';
        $remark = 'GOOD';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 50 && $value->tot_score <= 59.99) {
        $grade = 'C';
        $remark = 'ABOVE AVERAGE';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 45 && $value->tot_score <= 49.99) {
        $grade = 'D';
        $remark = 'AVERAGE';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 40 && $value->tot_score <= 44.99) {
        $grade = 'E';
        $remark = 'FAIR';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 0 && $value->tot_score <= 39.99) {
        $grade = 'F';
        $remark = 'NEEDS IMPROVEMENT';
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    $total += $value->tot_score;

    ?>
    
//modified here

<?php
$eachgrade = array($grade);
$gradenum = array_count_values($eachgrade);
foreach ($gradenum as $key=>$gvalue) {
    echo $key ."=". $gvalue;
}
?>
```

My output is
C=1 B=1 B=1

It should be
C=1 B=2

Comment: Stick each occurrence into an array, and use `array_count_values` afterwards. Trim off a +/- from your grade values first, before you stick them into that array, if you want to count B+, B and B- all as a `B`.

Comment: @CBroe please check my modified code. My output is not right. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You only have one single letter in $grade, because you are overwriting that variable all the time, instead of adding the individual grades to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to iterate over all grades and count the grades, e.g. in a hashmap
2. After you iterated over all grades you can iterate over your hashmap and print the grades with their counts

**NOTICE:** Do not open and close the php with `<?php` and `?>` all the time, if it is not necessary.

-> clean code -> better overview -> less errors

In your case there was also a missing closing bracket `}` after the `foreach` which caused your code to print the grades after each iteration instead of at the end only.

**Extended Code:**

```php
<?php

// init empty hashmap
$grades_count = [];

foreach ($subjectScores as $value) {

    if ($value->tot_score >= 90 && $value->tot_score <= 100) {
        $grade = 'A+';
        $remark = 'DISTINCTION';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 80 && $value->tot_score <= 89.99) {
        $grade = 'A';
        $remark = 'EXCELLENT';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 70 && $value->tot_score <= 79.99) {
        $grade = 'B+';
        $remark = 'VERY GOOD';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 60 && $value->tot_score <= 69.99) {
        $grade = 'B';
        $remark = 'GOOD';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 50 && $value->tot_score <= 59.99) {
        $grade = 'C';
        $remark = 'ABOVE AVERAGE';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 45 && $value->tot_score <= 49.99) {
        $grade = 'D';
        $remark = 'AVERAGE';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 40 && $value->tot_score <= 44.99) {
        $grade = 'E';
        $remark = 'FAIR';
    } elseif ($value->tot_score >= 0 && $value->tot_score <= 39.99) {
        $grade = 'F';
        $remark = 'NEEDS IMPROVEMENT';
    }


    // declare count for grade initially with 0
    if(isset($grades_count[$grade]) === false) { 
        $grades_count[$grade] = 0; 
    }

    // increment count for given grade
    $grades_count[$grade]++;
}

// loop over hashmap and print grades with 
// counts after all grades has been processed
foreach ($grades_count as $grade=>$count) {
    echo "$grade=$count ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. However, it is still showing the grades as this - C=1, B=1, B=1. It should be C =1, B=2.

Comment: @MaryPebbles This code does it. Please execute this sample: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9974dca28712d24da93b25d49a6eb711308fd03b. Otherwise, please share your `$subjectScores` values

Comment: you got it right. It worked indeed!. Thank you.